What is a proper analogy for the isomorphism $H^1_0(\Omega) \cap H^2(\Omega) \cong L^2(\Omega)$ for $-\Delta$ to heterogeneous elliptic operators?
Provide that $\Omega$ is a smooth domain. By solving the Laplace equation, we can build that
$$
\lVert u\rVert_{H^1_0(\Omega)}+\lVert u \rVert_{H^2(\Omega)} \cong \lVert -\Delta u \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}.
$$
This is generally not true if we replace $-\Delta$ with $-\nabla\cdot(A(x)\nabla\cdot)$, where $A(x)$ is only a $L^\infty$ function.
The question is which space can properly replace $H^2(\Omega)$ by providing a $L^2$ righthand term. According to De Giorgi's theory, we could place an Hölder continuous space here. But is it the tightest option to allow an isomorphism?
